# Encrypt/Decrypt using public/private key in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, cryptography, public-key-encryption, cryptojs

Hey i'm working on an angular 4 project and i need to encrypt and decrypt data using private and public keys , i found cryptojs library but it didn't had this type of data encryption/decryption, Is there any way to do it using this library , or another ?

Answer (score 2):

Data is not encrypted with asymmetric encryption, rather symmetric encryption such as [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is used.

Asymmetric encryption is very slow and the data size it can encrypt must be less than the key size. Symmetric encryption is fast and AES has essentially no data size limit.

If asymmetric encryption (public/private key pair) is required and the data is larger then the asymmetric key size the general solution is to use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: In my case i only want to encrypt some form fields , but i need to keep it asymmetric

Comment: 1. Why do you require asymmetric encryption. 2. With a 2048-bit key the data size is limited to less than 255 bytes.

Comment: Ok then , so this means that there is no way to use asymmetric encryption

Comment: 5b254b25e11a883484e88347 that's an example of an id (it's plain text) that i need to encrypt

Comment: See the last sentence in the answer, that allows use of asymmetric keys and symmetric encryption. There is some overhead of the  asymmetric encrypted symmetric key.

Comment: The deal is: Do not use asymmetric encryption unless separate encryption and decryption keys are required. asymmetric encryption is no more secure that symmetric encryption encryption.